# Is it possible to have a function output a generator expression and a value at the same time

Tags: python, function

I wanted to have one function output a generator expression as well as a value (string, integer, list, tuple, etc.), I tried a making one, it looked like this:

```
def func():
    for x in range(3):
        yield x
    return "Hello World"

print(func())
```

I ran debug, it seems to run the return but doesn't output anything when I print the result

```
<generator object func at 0x7fb35a69ac80>
```

why is this happening and how can I solve this issue of it running the return statement but not returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value in a generator is expressed as part of the data in the `StopIteration` exception. This exception occurs when you call `next` on a generator that has exhausted all of its remaining values.

Here is a brief example of how it can be used.

```
def func():
    for x in range(3):
        yield x
    return "Hello World"

gen = func()

try:
    while True:
        print(next(gen))
except StopIteration as e:
    print(e.value)
```

```
0
1
2
Hello World
```

Comment: Is there a way to output the generator expression and the returned value together? something like `(<generator object func at 0x7fb35a69ac80>, "Hello World")`

Comment: @pockspocky nope. You only reach the return value after youve done yielding values. The generator also stops at each yield statement until `next` is called on it. So there would be no way to return both at once.